# Android snackbar

Tags: android, android-snackbar

in my app i'm using a download DB sql lite and i have set this code to return a message for terminated download

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        if(first) {
            File dbPath = getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME);
            if (dbPath.exists()) {
                DBProvider provider = new DBProvider(MainActivity.this);
                database_comune_dao commune_dao = new database_comune_dao(provider.getDb());
                FirstProjectApplication.allComunes.clear();
                FirstProjectApplication.allComunes = commune_dao.getAllComune();


            }


            return "SUCCESS";

        }
```

i would like to change the return message with the new Snackbar of Material Design and this is the code

```
Snackbar.with(getApplicationContext()) // context
                .text("SUCCESS") // text to display
                .show(this);
```

i have try to change return whit this code but i have error.
Any idea how to set this snackbar for this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to achieve, post the code of your failed attempt and the error you obtained?

Answer (score 2):

You must use:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
        Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,"Your text",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**mainactivity.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Snackbar]

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `SnackBar` with following this syntax :

```
Snackbar.make(view, message, duration)
        .setAction(action message, click listener)
        .show();
```

you can avoid `setAction()` but `make()` and `show()` must be there, for more information please refer [this](https://knowandroidblog.wordpress.com/2015/10/27/snackbar-bye-bye-toast/)